# display:inline doesnt work but display:flex does

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, I am able to get a horizontal nav bar one way but not the other, and I am getting confused as to why. Strange things happen when I use `float:left` as well, so I'm not sure if I've got my elements labeled in the best format. The relevant html and css are below:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="navtext">
        <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="p2.html">P2</a></li>
        <li><a href="p3.html">P3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
.main-nav {
    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
    padding-left: 60px; 
    padding-right: 60px; 
    background-image: url("images/navimage.jpg");
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 10px black;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}


.navtext {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 3rem;
    margin: none;
    display: flex;
}
```

I've tried doing the whole nav as main-nav but then list style: none has no effect

EDIT: I'm also having difficulties getting the padding to effect the gaps between index p2 and p3. I'm putting padding into the `.navtext` and it just effects the padding around all three links treated as one rather than padding between them all.

Comment: can you describe your problem more clearer, maybe put some screenshot. i think i could help if theres more information about your question.

Comment: Please be more clear and post a jsfiddle

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/bhjkbeu8/ ] here is fiddle for your edit section.  your css selector for  padding li element should be like this .navtext li{ }  and MR. Robert already describe the whole display section for you. so I think you are clear about what you want. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:inline` says, "Hey, treat this element exactly as if it was a piece of text, like an `em`, `span`, or `a` element." You can't specify the width of an inline element; it just takes up as much space as the text inside it, which is why it's not working for your `ul`. 99% of the time, you only want to use `display:inline` on actual text. You probably don't want it on a `ul`, since a `ul` is a *container* for text, and isn't actually text itself.

`display:block` makes the element expand to fill up the width of its container, unless you specify a `width`. So if you put `display:block` on your `ul`, it will expand to fill the width of your `nav` element.

`display:flex` is a fairly new feature that has the same behavior as `display:block`, but then lots of other cool stuff too that you're not currently using, like making everything inside the element expand to fill up available space.

`display:inline-block` is like `display:inline` in that elements "flow" with the text around them, and like `display:block` in that you can specify the element's width.

If this was 5 years ago, before most web browsers supported `display:flex`, you'd probably want `display:block` on the `ul` and `display:inline-block` on the `li`. But today, `display:flex` is a great option for nav bars.